# How to get foreign dictionary without changing locale on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to keep the US English locale setting and Qwerty layout, but change the language of the dictionary used for autocorrection in the Messaging app.

Possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is [an open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-keyboard/+bug/1273275) since January 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Not officaly yet. The choice of dictionary is limited to the default language keyboard layout. Unlike desktop Ubuntu where its possible to combine foreign dictictionary with english QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: A source, or timeframe for resolution? This is literally stopping me from using my device.